# Flat space limit of metric blows up in different coordinates

Tags: general-relativity

Consider the metric

$$ds^2=dv^2-dt^2+v^2 \mathcal{R}^2 d\Omega^2_3,$$

where $d\Omega^2_{3}$ is the metric of the $3$-sphere, and $\mathcal{R}$ is the radius. I want to bring the metric in the form

$$ds^2=\frac{du^2}{f(u)}+e^{2A(u)}(-f(u)dt^2+\mathcal{R}^2 d\Omega^2_3).$$

This can be done by substituting $v=e^u$, and up to various rescalings of the coordinates we identify $f(u)=e^{-2u}$, $A(u)=u$. In this new coordinate system, the scalar curvature is

$$R \propto e^{-2u},$$

whereas the Kretschmann invariant is

$$R_{\mu \nu \kappa \lambda} R^{\mu \nu \kappa \lambda} \propto e^{-4u}.$$

Taking the limit $v \rightarrow 0$ corresponds to shrinking the radius of the $3$-sphere to zero, and thus we are left with flat space. But the appropriate limit in the $u$-coordinates is $u \rightarrow -\infty$, where the curvature invariants blow up. This does not make sense, as in that limit the invariants must vanish. I thought I must have done a mistake in calculating the invariants, but I really can't find one. Can anyone think of what might by going wrong?

Comment: Seems like only a sign has stopped you from getting the right answer - you must have a mistake somewhere? Trust me when I say it's almost impossible to do a long curvature calculation without a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Why would you call $\mathcal{R}$ the radius? Of what? The flat space limit is $\mathcal{R}=1$, any other value is a 5D “hyperconical” spacetime with a solid angle deficit (or excess) around the origin.

Comment: @A.V.S. Good point on $\mathcal{R}$. Since the metric is 4D, did you mean that this space can be viewed as isometrically embedded in 5 ambient dimensions? Or did you consider $\mathcal{R}$ the 5th dimension?

Comment: @safesphere *Since the metric is 4D* No it is 5D. We have $t$, $v$ (or $u$ in the second equation), and three coordinates on the 3-sphere.

Comment: @A.V.S. I thought so as well, but if you drop $\mathcal{R}$ from the first equation, what you get looks like the Minkowski metric with $d\Omega$ being the angular part that mathematicians often call "the spherical metric". So I think this is what the OP meant by "the metric of the 3-sphere", just the angular part. I hope she can clarify.